# Activitiy's email content - how is it generated and can it be changed?

Tags: email, activities, core

When assigning an activity in CiviCRM to a contact using the field "Assigned to". Unless deactivated those contacts get send an email.

My question is, how this email is generated - is there a template somewhere? Or any other way teh email could be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the template you're looking for can be found at `Administer -> CiviMail -> Message Templates`, i.e, navigate to `civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1` and click on `System Workflow Messages`.

The template name is `Cases - Send Copy of an Activity`. Note that you don't need to enable CiviCase component to view this template. It is displayed by default and used to send emails to assignees(both case and normal activities).

Also, if you want to disable the sending of email to assignee for some activity types, there is a new configuration setting added at `civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1`.

[image]

The setting is only displayed when the above checkbox of `Notify Activity Assignee` is enabled.

Comment: Thank you very much - I thought that template was only for case activities but it works for "regular activities as well.